# C language: uninitialized local variables (arm-none-eabi-gcc)

Tags: struct, initialization, stm32, partial, local-variables

Partial initialization of the Init structures in the CubeMX generated code is quite common:

```
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void) 
{

GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;

...

/*Configure GPIO pin : MY_PIN_13_Pin */ 
GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = MY_PIN_13_Pin; 
GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP; 
GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH; 
HAL_GPIO_Init(MY_PIN_13_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);
```

`GPIO_InitStruct.Pull` is left out. According to the language standard, the initial state of local variables is undefined, so the unassigned fields of an Init structure must contain garbage, which cannot be tolerated by any program.

Does it mean that local variables get zero-initialized after all (research does not really support this conjecture; my research, that is)? In case of this particular toolchain, at least.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the exmaple you gave the struct has an automatic storage and not initializing it explicitly means its value may not be determined.

From C99 standard (6.7.8.10 - Initialization);

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate. [...]

In this case those structs will be placed on the stack and counting on it (the stack) being zero-initialized before main is still not sufficient. First of all, such zero-initialization may or may not happen based on the implementation. Secondly, if you have initialization functions called in a chain like this:

```
initA();
initB();
```

and the structure in question happens to be used in such way in `initB()`, then its uninitialized fields will contain values leftover on stack that was previously used by `initA()` and will likely no longer be zeroes. Lastly, even if your stack is initialized with zeroes, it may change if you for example move your code into the FreeRTOS task, in which case it the fresh initialized stack value is `0xA5A5A5A5` and not zeroes. This may result in the initialization code suddenly breaking even though you've made no explicit change to it.

You may choose to initialize the structure with zeroes like so:

```
memset(&GPIO_InitStruct, 0, sizeof(GPIO_InitStruct));
```

but there may be cases where the result of the default `0` field is either not something you would expect or such value may even be forbidden for a given field.

Personally I'd assume that if the code was generated in such way, the uniinitialized fields would be unused, at least in this combination of values. However after looking at the source of `HAL_GPIO_Init` it does seem like an oversight, as all fields - including the uninitialized `Pull` field - are asserted to be in range of allowed values right at the beginning of the function.

To further elaborate - back in the "StdPeriph days", there used to be functions present that did just what you're asking for - initialized all fields of a struct to default values that seemed to be most intuitive for a given peripheral.

For example in case of the GPIO:

```
void GPIO_StructInit(GPIO_InitTypeDef* GPIO_InitStruct)
{
  /* Reset GPIO init structure parameters values */
  GPIO_InitStruct->GPIO_Pin  = GPIO_Pin_All;
  GPIO_InitStruct->GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_IN;
  GPIO_InitStruct->GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_2MHz;
  GPIO_InitStruct->GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct->GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
}
```

To my knowledge such functions are not present in current version of the HAL library, therefore you're left with either zero-initializing the structs (which may result in behavior you don't expect) or initializing all the other fields by hand (which means some work on your side, likely writing functions similar to `GPIO_StructInit` above).

Answer (score 0):

If a structure has automatic storage duration and no initialization is specified, the initial content of its fields will be Indeterminate Value.  For fields that are not of a character type, any attempt to use the value may behave in unpredictable fashion, except that copying a struct which has Indeterminate Value in some of its fields will have no unusual effects beyond storing Indeterminate Value in the corresponding fields of the destination.

If you want to default-zero initialize an automatic struct, the easiest way to do so is generally to add `={0}` following the declaration.  Note that such a form will work for just almost any kind of structure, regardless of the types contained therein, since a literal zero is a valid initialization value for any integer type, floating-point type, or pointer type, and since the 0 will be applied to the first member of any nested structures or union types.  The only potential issue would be if one of the members of the structure is a union whose first member is not the largest.  In that case, there would be no guarantee about the initialization of any storage which is not used by the first union member but is used by others.  Otherwise, using `{0}` initialization with a structure of automatic duration will initialize to the default value that a static structure would receive on program startup.